# Where do I connect this wire from the side panel fan?

Tags: fan, connector, wiring, defective-hardware

Is the wire broken? Where do I connect it?

[image]

Comment: Connector is missing in the end.

Comment: It will be 2 pin molex large connector.

Comment: You don't need that fan. Get rid of it. If you need cooling, clean your heatsinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an elegant solution at all, but I've successfully connected such crippled fan to Molex disk drive connector ([AMP MATE-N-LOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector) female connector from PSU):

- fan red wire to yellow (+12 V)
- fan black wire to black (GND)

[Google "molex fan"](https://www.google.pl/search?q=molex+fan&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) and you will see there are connectors available, it's nothing unusual. The difference is your wires are loose, without any connector on them.

I got rid of about 1 cm of wire insulation on both wires, split them apart, then stabilized them inside Molex connector with fragments of toothpicks (the diameter turned out to be just right).

**MacGyver approved. Still you do it at your own risk.**

Comment: why not buy a molex connector (around 1€), crimp the metal pins to the cable with regular pliers and save yourself from fiddling around with toothpicks? Also, one has to be aware that cheap fans are normally unbearably loud at 12V - I think that should be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

That's definitely torn loose from its connector. Consider replacing the fan with one with a 3- or 4-pin connector if your motherboard has a standard chassis fan connector free.

Comment: Also consider investing in a can of compressed air.